# Autofac registertypes with interface and class having same name with prefix I for interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am currently implementing asp.net mvc app. i am using Autofac DI and would like to check if I have class and interface with same name prefix with I. so to resolve every registration, do I need to add mapping entry for each interface. there are more than 50 classes in current project.

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1):

You could do something in Starup using reflection to check for names based on your convention.

I've done similar, but checking for the existence of an attribute:

```
private static void RegisterServices()
{
    var serviceList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(aa => aa.FullName.IndexOf("DI.Web.Ex09", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
        .SelectMany(a =>
            a.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.HasAttribute(typeof(InjectAttribute)) && t.IsPublic)
        );

    foreach (var t in serviceList)
    {
        var attribs = t.GetCustomAttributes<InjectAttribute>();
        foreach (var attrib in attribs)
        {
            _builder.RegisterType(t)
                .As(attrib.BindingType).InstancePerRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

See the full example here:

https://github.com/ovation22/IntroToDependencyInjection/tree/master/DI.Web.Ex09